# Is it possible to show a tooltip on an ext.net grid?

Tags: ext.net

In an Ext.Net grid, is it possible to show a tooltip containing text based on the row/column where mouse is positioned ?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The following two samples should help.

1. Render a ToolTip on the GridPanel Row

http://examples.ext.net/#/Miscellaneous/ToolTips/GridPanel_Row_Tooltip/

1. Render a ToolTip on each individual GridPanel Cell

http://examples.ext.net/#/Miscellaneous/ToolTips/GridPanel_Cell_Tooltip/